# Identify pairs of matching records using Pandas for further analysis

Tags: pandas

I conduct a multiple choice survey at the start and end of the semester and I would like to analyze whether students answers to questions change significantly from begin to end.

There will be students who answer the first one and don't the second one and vice versa, for numerous reasons. I want to drop those from the analysis.

Note that the students don't all answer at the exact same time (or even day.) Some may do it the day before the assignment or the day after so I can't rely on the date/time. I have to rely on the matching of email addresses.

The questions have the usual "strongly agree or disagree, agree or disagree, or not sure.

My data file looks like this:

```
Email address: text
Time: date/time
Multiple Choice Q1: [agree, disagree, neutral]
Multiple Choice Q2: [agree, disagree, neutral]
```

1. I need to filter out the records for students who didn't answer twice (at begin and end of semester)
2. I need to come up with a way to quantify how much each answer changed.

I've played around with many ideas but they are all some form of brute-force old fashioned looping and saving.

Using Pandas I suspect there's a much more elegant way to do it.

---

Here is a model of the input:

```
input = pd.DataFrame({'email': 
                   ['joe@sample.com', 'jane@sample.com', 'jack@sample.com', 
                    'joe@sample.com', 'jane@sample.com', 'jack@sample.com', 'jerk@sample.com'],
                  'date': ['jan 1 2019', 'jan 2 2019', 'jan 1 2019',
                           'july 2, 2019', 'july 1 2019', 'july 1, 2019', 'july 1, 2019'],
                  'are you happy?': ["yes", "no", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no"],
                  'are you smart?': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes' , 'yes', 'yes']})
```

and here's a model of the output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'question': ['are you happy?', 'are you smart?'],
                       'change score': [+0.6, +1]})
```

#### What a great exercise, thanks for suggesting it.

The logic of the change scores are that for "are you happy?" Joe stayed the same, and jack and jane went from no to yes, so (0 + 1 + 1)/3. And for "are you smart?" all three went from no to yes so (1 + 1 + 1)/3 = 1. jerk@sample.com is not counted because he didn't respond to the beginning survey just the ending one.

---

Here are the first two lines of my data file:

```
Timestamp,Email Address,How I see myself [I am comfortable in a leadership position],How I see myself [I like and am effective working in a team],How I see myself [I have a feel for business],How I see myself [I have a feel for marketing],How I see myself [I hope to start a company in the future],How I see myself [I like the idea of working at a large company with a global impact],"How I see myself [Carreerwise, I think working at a startup is very risky]","How I see myself [I prefer an unstructured, improvisational job]",How I see myself [I like to know exactly what is expected of me so I can excel],How I see myself [I've heard that I can make a lot of money in a startup and that is important to me so I can support myself and my family],How I see myself [I would never work at a significant company (like Google)],How I see myself [I definitely want to work at a significant company (like Facebook)],How I see myself [I have confidence in my intuitions about creating a successful business],How I see myself [The customer is always right],How I see myself [Don't ask users what they want: they don't know what they want],How I see myself [If you create what customers are asking for you will always be behind],"How I see myself [From the very start of designing a business, it is crucial to talk to users and customers]",What is your best guess of your career 3 years after your graduation?,Class,Year of expected graduation (undergrad or grad),"How I see myself [Imagine you've been working on a new product for months, then discover a competitor with a  similar idea.  The best response to this is to feel encouraged because this means that what you are working on is a real problem.]",How I see myself [Most startups fail],How I see myself [Row 20],"How I see myself [For an entrepreneur, Strategic skills are more important than  having a great (people) network]","How I see myself [Strategic vision is crucial to success, so that one can consider what will happen several moves ahead]",How I see myself [It's important to stay focused on your studies rather than be dabbling in side projects or businesses],How I see myself [Row 23],How I see myself [Row 22]
8/30/2017 18:53:21,s@b.edu,I agree,Strongly agree,I agree,I'm not sure,I agree,I agree,I'm not sure,I agree,I agree,I'm not sure,I disagree,I disagree,I disagree,I disagree,I disagree,Strongly disagree,I agree,working with  film production company,Sophomore,2020,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: looking at your data it seems quite simple, you need to 1) filter out records which are `< 2` at certain dates, & quantify each response. for number two this is usually the domain of market researchers what I usually do (for them) is to provide a 1-5 metric based on the answers and they analyse and weight accordingly.

Comment: adding to @Datanovice said, it would help if you can create a dummy dataframe which replicates your original df and an expected output with the explanations

Comment: Great suggestion because it forced me to confront specifically what I need. I've updated the question.

Comment: @pitosalas I've added an answer, but now that i think further it might be a good idea to split out the Answer column then you can test to see if someone went from `yes` to `no` or `no` to `yes` you can then give a rank accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is super helpful. I will try it asap!

Answer (score 1):

starting with your initial data frame,

first, we convert your date into a proper datetime.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

then we create two variables, the first ensures there are more than 2 counts of an email per person, the 2nd that they fall into months 1 & 7 respectively.

(assuming you *may* have duplicate entires) `.loc` allows us to use boolean conditions with our dataframe.

```
s = df.groupby('email')['email'].transform('count') >= 2
months = [1,7] # start & end of semester.
df2 = df.loc[(df['date'].dt.month.isin(months)) & (s)]
```

---

```
print(df2)
    email       date            are you happy? are you smart?
0   joe@sample.com 2019-01-01            yes             no
1  jane@sample.com 2019-01-02             no             no
2  jack@sample.com 2019-01-01             no             no
3   joe@sample.com 2019-07-02            yes            yes
4  jane@sample.com 2019-07-01            yes            yes
5  jack@sample.com 2019-07-01            yes            yes
```

now, we need to re-shape our data so we can run some logical tests more easily.

```
df3 = (
    df2.set_index(["email", "date"])
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "answer", "level_2": "question"})
    .sort_values(["email", "date"])
)

             email       date        question answer  
0  jack@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you happy?     no    
1  jack@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you smart?     no    
2  jack@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you happy?    yes    
3  jack@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you smart?    yes
```

now, we need to figure out if Jack's answer changed from the start of the semester and the end, and if so, we assign a score, we will leverage `map` and create a dictionary from the output dataframe.

```
score_dict = dict(zip(output["question"], output["change score"]))

s2 = df3.groupby(["email", "question"])["answer"].apply(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()))

df3.loc[(s2) & (df3["date"].dt.month == 7), "score"] = df3["question"].map(
    score_dict
)
```

---

```
print(df3)

              email       date        question answer  score
4   jack@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you happy?     no    NaN
5   jack@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you smart?     no    NaN
10  jack@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you happy?    yes    0.6
11  jack@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you smart?    yes    1.0
2   jane@sample.com 2019-01-02  are you happy?     no    NaN
3   jane@sample.com 2019-01-02  are you smart?     no    NaN
8   jane@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you happy?    yes    0.6
9   jane@sample.com 2019-07-01  are you smart?    yes    1.0
0    joe@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you happy?    yes    NaN
1    joe@sample.com 2019-01-01  are you smart?     no    NaN
6    joe@sample.com 2019-07-02  are you happy?    yes    NaN
7    joe@sample.com 2019-07-02  are you smart?    yes    1.0
```

logically, we only want to apply a score to any value that changed and is not in the penultimate month.

so, Joe has a value of NaN for his `are you happy` question as he selected Yes in the first semester and Yes for the 2nd.

you might want to add some more logic for the scoring, to look at Y/N differently, and you'll need to clean up your dataframe from looking at your first row - but something along these lines should work.